# How do target polymorphic model through many models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 4 classes:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memories
  has_many :playlists
  has_many :items, as: 'playlist_items', through: :playlists
  has_many :items, as: 'memory_items', through: :memories
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :itemable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end

class Playlist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :items, as: :itemable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true
end

class Memory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :items, as: :itemable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true
end
```

I would like to be able to get from current_user to the items of either type, i.e. Memory or Playlist. But right now I can only get to 1 set.. if I have this in User:

```
has_many :items, through: :playlists
```

I can't currently figure out how to do both in a list. 'As' seems to have no effect. Any suggestions would be very helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have both associations with the same name, you can specialize specifying the source. Try like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memories
  has_many :playlists
  has_many :playlist_items, through: :playlists, source: :items
  has_many :memory_items, through: :memories, source: :items
end
```

Then of course you use `user.playlist_items` and `user.memory_items` instead.

Comment: I guess he can define a method all_items as playlist_items + memory_items.

Comment: @JefRice glad to help. Could you please accept the answer?